# Looking for a proof that a set limit point of the range of a sequence, is a sequence limit point for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

A *sequence* limit point $p$ of a sequence $\{u_n\}$ satisfies:
$$ ∀ϵ>0,∀M∈\mathbb N,∃m≥M,d(u_m,p)<ϵ \tag{1}$$

A *set* limit point $p$ of the range of a sequence $\{u_n\}$ satisfies:
$$ ∀ϵ>0,∃n∈\mathbb N, u_n\neq p, d(u_n,p)<ϵ \tag{2}$$

How to prove that $(2)$ implies $(1)$ ?

I've tried every other way, but don't know how to handle `∃m≥M`.

Edit -

- I understand that in the sequence Limit Point definition, for each $M$ there is one or more $m$ associated to it, this implies that we can fix a bijection between an element $\mathbb N$ and an associated $m$. Hence, this definition  is equivalent to: "there are countable infinitely many terms of $\{u_n\}$  whithin every neighborhood of $p$".
- I also understand that set LP implies that there are infinitely many elements (here, terms of $\{u_n\}$) in the neighborhood of the set LP. Hence, the definition mentioned in the above bullet is met, and $p$ is a seequence LP.

Comment: Please include your attempts in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply (2) several times, first with $\varepsilon=1/2$, which gives $u_{n_1}$, then with $\varepsilon = d(u_{n_1},p)/2 \in (0,1/4)$ in place of $\varepsilon$, which gives $u_{n_2}$ and so on.

Note that the sequence $d(u_{n_i},p)$ is less than ${1 \over 2^i}$ and thus tends to 0.

The sequence $n_1$, $n_2$... must take infinitely many distinct values. If not, the sequence $d(u_{n_i},p)$ would assume only finitely many values, all strictly positive, and thus would not tends to $0$. So we can find an increasing subsequence to the sequence $n_i$ which proves (1).

Comment: You have proven that there exists a subsequence converging to $p$, which is equivalent to $(1)$ but not the same exactly.

Comment: Yes. If you  have an increasing subsequence that converges to $p$, you can find arbitrarily large indices for which the related terms are in the ball of radius epsilon around p.